# Is it possible to loop array without using foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I have a html array structure..

I output this array with foreach loops. (inside get_output functions)

Is it possible to output results without using foreach?

```
$schema = array(
    array(
        'tag' => 'div',
        'class' => 'lines',
        array(
            'tag' => 'div',
             array(
                'tag' => 'span',
                'style' => 'margin:10px; padding:10px',
                'key' => '$key-countryname',
            ),
            'key' => '$value-country',
        ),
        array(
            'tag' => 'div',
             array(
                'tag' => 'span',
                'style' => 'margin:10px; padding:10px',
                'key' => '$key-countryname',
            ),
            'key' => '$value-country',
        ),
    )
);
```

My function is using foreach loops to output results

```
function get_output($schema, $t = -2){
    $t++; $tag = ""; $atts = array(); $keys = array(); $code = array();

    foreach($schema as $k => $v){        
        if(is_array($v)){
            $keys[] = get_output($v, $t);
        } else {
            switch($k){
                case "tag": $tag = $v; break;
                case "key": $keys[] = $v; break;
                case "type": break;
                default: $atts[$k] = $v; break;
            }
        }    
    }
    if(0 < $t){ $code[] = "\n".str_repeat("\t", $t); }
    if($tag){
        $code[] = "<$tag"; foreach($atts as $k=>$v){ $code[] = ' '.$k.'="'.$v.'"'; } $code[] = ">";
        $code = array(implode('', $code));
    }
    foreach($keys as $k){ $code[] = $k; } 
    if($tag){
        $code[] = "\n".str_repeat("\t", $t);
        $code[] = '</'.$tag.'>'; 
    }
    //print_r($code);
    return implode("", $code);
}
```

Comment: Yes, use a simple `for` loop... ;)

Comment: `array_map()`, `array_walk()` or maybe [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) ?

Comment: @alfasin I'm looking for native php function that has its own foreach function inside.

Comment: why do you ask? It seems to me that from the efficiency point of view, you biggest concern is using recursion, otherwise your code seems quite fine

Comment: @HamZa array_walk_recursive could be good alternative I will try to implement it.

Comment: @IvanHušnjak But It is to hard to undestanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while` and `for` are perfectly valid ways to loop array:

```
$a = array(1,2,3); // indexed
$b = array(
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
    'c' => 3
); // associative

echo '$a indexed with "for": <br />';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++) {
   echo $a[$i] . '<br />';
}
echo '$a indexed with "while": <br />';
$i = 0; // reset counter
while ($i < count($a)) {
   echo $a[$i] . '<br />';
   $i++;
}

echo '$b assoc with "for": <br />';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++) {
   echo key($b) . ' => ' . current($b) . '<br />';
   next($b); // step forward
}
echo '$b assoc with "while": <br />';
reset($b); // rewind array cursor to start
while ($value = current($b)) {
   echo key($b) . ' => ' . $value . '<br />';
   next($b); // step forward
}
```

Also as you already implemented in your second code snippet, multi-dim array can be looped with recursion (though compared to nested loops it consumes more memory)

Comment: Is it possible to use count function to loop multidimensional array?

Comment: @DenizPorsuk no, `count()` only counts items on first level, but as HamZa pointed, you can use `array_walk_recursive()` it should be efficient than simple recursion

Comment: I suppose to use next() for easy comparement. Multidimensional array might problem.

Comment: `foreach` is the most performant way to iterate over an array. I'd only use something else if there is a real need.